# Combination with Repetitions and a bound on set

Tags: combinatorics

Emily really loves chocolate, but lately she has been indecisive on what kinds of chocolate to eat. She currently has a collection of various chocolate squares of 1 square inch, 2 square inches, and 3 square inches.

- Milk Chocolate

  - 5 one square inch chocolates
  - 3 two square inch chocolates
  - 7 three square inch chocolates
- White Chocolate

  - 4 one square inch chocolates
  - 2 two square inch chocolates
  - 1 three square inch chocolates
- Dark Chocolate

  - 2 one square inch chocolates
  - 3 two square inch chocolates
  - 2 three square inch chocolates

If Emily is only allowed to eat 18 square inches of chocolate today, then how many combinations can she choose from to eat her chocolate?

I have had difficulty answering this question. The part that is hindering me is the limit of 18 square inches. What is the procedure used to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a generating function that represent sums with the chocolates, differentiating by weight and colour.

For the Milk chocolate I define 
$$M(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12}+x^{15}+x^{18}+x^{21})$$

this represent all combinations of only Milk chocolate, taking from $0$ squares of each weight to the maximum.

For the White chocolate I define
$$W(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)$$

And for Dark chocolate
$$D(x)=(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6)$$

When you expand the expression of $M*W*D$ the coefficient for the power of 18 let to you all the possible combinations differentiating by colour and square weight.

If, as someone says in a comment, the child can eat any amount from 1 to 18 then you can sum all the coefficients from power 1 to 18. This will be the amount of different combinations that sum 18 or less.

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: @Flowers Be more specific please. I dont understand your doubt.

Comment: @Masacroso: I am not sure that Emily *has* to eat 18 square inches of chocolate. She is allowed 18; maybe she could have less.

Comment: O, I will try explain: parenthesis mean groups where you choose, each parenthesis express a colour and weight. The power means the value what you are searching some combination and the coefficient the frequency, in this problem all coefficients are 1, we arent choosing by probability or so. In the final polynomial each addend represent the amount of sums (aka combinations) that let by result it power.

Comment: @posilon then sum all coefficients from power 1 to 18.

Comment: What do you mean by "power means the value what you are searching some combination?"

Comment: Power means total weight of an election based on chocolate colour and number of squares of a base weight for this problem.